# Saving formatted timestring as file name problem in c#

Tags: c#

HI guys, 
I only started c# recently so I'm not 100% familiar with it's syntax yet and I got into a problem. I'd like to write the current time into a filename. I'm using the following code:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now;
string dateString = string.Format(@"Z:\test\{0}.bmp",now.ToString("s"));
bitmap.Save(dateString);
```

Now this gives me a can't access filepath error. Apparently it has something to do with the ":" characters at the time part (at least when I give a now.ToString("d") ) it saves fine. 
Any idea whats causing this? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments guys, got it working with a different format,looks a bit ugly but have accept that for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "s" format will create a filename of something like:

```
2009-06-15T13:45:30.bmp
```

That's just not a valid filename, due to the colon. Either replace the colon with another character after calling ToString, or use a different format.

Note that "d" won't always work either, as it *can* include "/" in the name, depending on the culture.

Personally I'd suggest something like "yyyyMMdd-HHmmss" which will give you something like

```
20090615-134530.bmp
```

Comment: Ah well,have to settle with "-" characters then. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the code, the Windows filesystems won't allow the use of a colon (or several other "special" characters) in a filename.  So the issue is happening at the OS level, not in your code.

You'll want to strip out those characters and/or [format the timestamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) differently to use it as a filename.

Answer (score 1):

Some characters are not valid in filenames on Windows - See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is not related to c#.

Comment: Just my luck that the format I found nice is not supported by windows.Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

That is caused by the Windows file system, which disallows `:`'s in file names.

Answer (score 1):

':' are invalid characters for naming a file. You'll need to determine some other valid character to substitute for ':' before attempting to save the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class SPStringUtils
{
    public static string MakeFilename(this DateTime dt)
    {
        return dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss");
    }

    public static string MakeFilename(this DateTime dt, string format)
    {
        return string.Format(format, MakeFilename(Now));
    }
}

...
Console.WriteLine(Now.MakeFilename(@"c:\logs\log{0}.log");
```

Answer (score 0):

There can't be no ':' in a file name, that's why.